# Delete files older than X days in unix shell script excluding subdirectories and schedule via autosys

Tags: shell-script, autosys

I am using the below script to delete files from the folder

`script.sh` file contains only this line:

```
find /usr/filesfolder -type f -iname '*' -mindepth 1 -mtime +1825 -exec rm {} \
```

Autosys job is always failing with the below error output:

```
/usr/scripts/cleanupfiles.sh[5]: .[5]: .[5]: .[5]: .[5]: .[5]: .[5]: .[5]: .[5]: .[5]: 
/usr/scripts/cleanupfiles.sh[5]: .[5]: .[5]: .[5]: .[5]: .[5]: .[5]: .[5]: .[5]: .[5]:
/usr/scripts/cleanupfiles.sh[5]: .[5]: .[5]: .[5]: .[5]: .[5]: .[5]: .[5]: .[5]: .[5]:
/usr/scripts/cleanupfiles.sh[5]: .[5]: .[5]: .[5]: .[5]: .[5]: .[5]: .[5]: .[5]: .[5]:
/usr/scripts/cleanupfiles.sh[5]: .[5]: .[5]: .[5]: .[5]: .[5]: .[5]: .[5]: .[5]: .[5]:
```

Comment: The error indicates that there are more lines in your file. The ``\`` at the end escapes the newline (it acts as a line continuation).  What is the next line in the script after the `find` command?

Comment: These are all the lines after that command      
date >> $log
chmod 644 $log

exit 0

Comment: @DEV I noticed that no one commented on the "Autosys" aspect of this question. Could you please share with us how you implemented this within the context of Autosys?

Answer (score 1):

The `-exec` option to find must be terminated with a semicolon (and escaped from your shell), such as `-exec rm {} \;`

Comment: Also `-iname '*'` and `-mindepth 1` can be dropped completely as they do not do anything.

Comment: I tried                                                                                                                               
find /usr/filesfolder   -iname '*' -mindepth 1 -mtime +1825 -type f -exec rm {} \; 
Still it says /usr/scripts/cleanupfiles.sh[5]: .[5]: .[5]: .[5]: .[5]: .[5]: .[5]: .[5]: .[5]: .[5]: RECURSSION TOO DEEP